# Should constructors for WCF Services use faults for error handling?

Tags: wcf, web-services, constructor, soapfault

I have a wcf service. The service itself (class that inherits the [ServiceContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute(VS.85).aspx)) has a constructor that sometimes throws exceptions. I want to present the user a message if the service fails. Should I use faults like I would for a service method?

Comment: Why does your WCF service have a constructor that can fail? And, quite honestly...why does it have a constructor at all? WCF can create and destroy service instances at will...your just asking for problems by using a constructor, particularly if it can throw exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fault is generally meant to provide error information across service boundaries, and in most cases, a fault is sent as a response to a malformed or invalid request message.  Given that, I would say a fault doesn't make sense here.

I agree with the above commenter that a constructor for a service class should avoid throwing exceptions.  If your service is sessionful, you may want to consider a design where you do this type of initialization as the result of a specific service operation.  This can be done in WCF by marking such a service operation with "[IsInitiating = true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isinitiating.aspx)" in the [OperationContract] attribute.  At that point, you **would** be able to generate a fault and have some hope of it reaching the intended client.